Equation relating the Riemann zeta function and the digamma function
While going through a few functional equations for the Riemann zeta function I stumbled upon one connecting it to the Digamma function $\psi(x)$, the formula is:
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{\sin(\pi s)}{\pi}\int^{\infty}_{0}x^{-s}(\ln(1+x)-\psi(1+x))dx$$
this is supposed to be proven in " Integralen voor de
ζ
-functie van Riemann. Mathematica (Zutphen) B5," by N.G. de Bruijn, but I can't seem to find this article anywhere.
I then tried to prove it starting from $$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^{x}-1}dx$$ and using the known formula
$\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)}$
but I can't seem to find a way.
Does anyone know where to find the article I mentioned or another proof?
